# How to create a CreatedTime column with differing behaviour

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a new createdtime column to a table. But, I want that all the previous entries in the table show '19700101' date while all the new entries from this point forward (i.e. after the new column is introduced) should show the current date by using the getDate()

Comment: why -1, why close it. Either tell me why this is not a valid question or point me towards a valid solution if it is already on stackoverflow

Comment: First create the column with default as '19700101'. Then alter the column and change the default to GetDate(). Simple

Comment: i tried that already and it doesnt work. if you see a little bit into it then you will see why it does not work :). even if it worked then it would have changed all the previous values to current date.

Comment: @LivingThing - I would assert that you're incorrect, because I've just added an answer with a script showing it working.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you are right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Roopesh's comments do work just fine:

```
create table T (ID int not null,Col1 varchar(9) not null)
go
insert into T(ID,Col1) values (1,'abc'),(2,'def')
go
alter table T add CreatedDate date not null constraint DF_tmp default '19700101'
go
alter table T drop constraint DF_tmp
go
alter table T add constraint DF_Permanent
     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for CreatedDate
go
insert into T(ID,Col1) values (3,'ghi')
go
select * from T
```

Result is:

```
ID          Col1      CreatedDate
----------- --------- -----------
1           abc       1970-01-01
2           def       1970-01-01
3           ghi       2014-06-13
```

This has the advantage that the column doesn't allow `NULL`s. If you use [Mikael's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24203436/15498), you *can* make the column non-nullable *after* you've applied the `UPDATE` but that's going to require two scans of the table (once to apply the `UPDATE`, the second time to check for any `NULL`s when making the column `not null`).

Comment: +1. The `not null` approach with my answer would more likely be just to add a `not null` column and then replace all values just like it is doing only it's not done from `null` but from a value. Nevertheless, your approach will of course be faster since it is updating some meta data instead of replacing all values in the table.

Answer (score 1):

First add a column that has the default value `getdate()`

```
alter table YourTable add createddate date default getdate()
```

The default value is not applied in this step. Every row has `null` as value for `createddate`.

Update the value of `createddate` to `1970-01-01` for all rows.

```
update YourTable set createddate = '1970-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--Create Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTestTable](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

--Put in some data
INSERT INTO [MyTestTable] (Name) VALUES ('Eoin')
INSERT INTO [MyTestTable] (Name) VALUES ('Living Thing')

GO

-- Add a new column datetime with a default value of min date
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTestTable ADD
    CreatedDate datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTestTable_CreatedDate DEFAULT Convert(Datetime, '19700101')
GO

-- Existing Records are now updated to Jan 1970
SELECT * FROM MyTestTable
GO
-- Alter the table again but with a new default
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTestTable
    DROP CONSTRAINT DF_MyTestTable_CreatedDate
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTestTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_MyTestTable_CreatedDate DEFAULT getdate() FOR CreatedDate
GO

--Put in some more data.

INSERT INTO [MyTestTable] (Name) VALUES ('John')

GO

-- newer Records are now updated to current date
SELECT * FROM MyTestTable
GO
```